# Get info from line above preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I've a log file that reads as

```
text message sent to client 1234 and mobileNo: 987654
Message: This is working
Confirmation No: ab123
text message sent to client 4321 and mobileNo: 456789
Message: This is not working 
Confirmation No:
```

I have to get an alert if there is no confirmation number (i.e. Confirmation No: )

I've written the following code:

```
    preg_match('/Confirmation No:\s*$/', $logLine, $match);
    $matchLine = implode(" ",$match);
    if ($matchLine == NULL) {
            echo "There is an empty Confirmation No";
    } else {
            echo "Confirmation No: " . $matchLine;
    }
```

This works fine and prints "There is an empty Confirmation No", if there is no confirmation.

But I would like to add clientID and MobileNo in the output too, i.e. **There is an empty confirmation for client 4321 on MobileNo: 456789.**

Can someone please advise, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using `if(empty($matchLine))`

Comment: Thanks @Thamilan. Sorry I wasn't clear enough with my requirement. I would like to add clientID and MobileNumber in the output too..

Comment: Does my answer work?

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("/Confirmation\sNo:\s(.*)..*client\s(\d+)\sand\smobileNo:\s(\d+)/ms", $string, $match);
if ($match[1] == "") {
        echo "There is an empty Confirmation No for client " . $match[2] . " on MobileNo: " . $match[3];
} else {
        echo "Confirmation No: " . $match[1];
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/qU7aP2/1

EDIT: I just noticed, maybe it's the other way around??
https://regex101.com/r/oY4hD9/1
`$pattern = "/client\s(\d+)\sand\smobileNo:\s(\d+)..*Confirmation\sNo:\s(\w+)/ms";`
I wasn't sure how the string was built. 
Not that if this is the regex pattern you need then the code $match[x] needs to change places.

Comment: Hey @Andreas, I tried your solution, but it checks for clients with confirmation number.. I would like where it is empty.. So tried 'client\s(\d+)\sand\smobileNo:\s(\d+)..*Confirmation\sNo:\s($)' but it didn't help..

Comment: Try: `$pattern = "/client\s(\d+)\sand\smobileNo:\s(\d+)..*Confirmation\sNo:(\w+|\s)/ms";` this may mean the value is " " and not empty

Comment: @RaviSingh what about this? http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fPO `preg_match_all("/client (\d+) .*?mobileNo: (\d+).*?Confirmation No\:(\s\w+|\s)/ms", $input_lines, $output_array);` in case of no confirmation it's a blank space, if there is a confirmation it's blankspaceAndNO. Edit, note it's a preg_match_all, so click that button in the link

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'd do the job:

```
// within the loop on the log file
if (preg_match('/\b(client \d*) and \b(mobileNo: \d*)/', $logLine, $m)) {
    $client = 'There is an empty confirmation for '.$m[1].' on '.$m[2];
}
if (preg_match('/Confirmation No: (\w*)$/', $logLine, $m) {
    if (empty($m[1])) {
        echo $client;
    } else {
        echo $logLine;
    }
    $client = '';
}
```